# Add padding to HTML displayed with a UITextView

Tags: html, ios, css, uitextview

I'm displaying HTML in a `UITextView` for a multitude of reasons I won't go into, but it's basically the only way that will work for me currently.

What I do, in a nutshell, is insert my HTML string into an HTML template I've designed, and then load the entire HTML string into the `UITextView` as an `NSAttributedString`, which is initialized using `data:options:documentAttributes`, passing in `[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType]` to the `options`.

Here's the current HTML template I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Answer</title>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
            <style>
                html { -webkit-test-size-adjust: none; }
                body { margin: 0px; padding:0px; font-family: -apple-system, 'HelveticaNeue'; font-size:{{fontSize}}px; color:{{textColor}}; }
                b, strong { font-weight: 600; }
                a { text-decoration: none; color: #0074B4; }
                a:active { color: #004C75; }
                ul { padding-left: 100px; }
                li { list-style-position: outside; }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{bodyContent}}
    </body>
</html>
```

The actual HTML string I want to display ends up in `{{bodyContent}}`, while some other properties populate the other variables wrapped in double braces. The issue seems to be none of my padding/margin changes seem to have any effect on the HTML once it's rendered in the `UITextView`.

Does anyone know how to go about getting these padding/margin changes to show up once the `UITextView` renders the completed `NSAttributedString`?